# Dynamic buffer size for flux

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, project-reactor

I have kafka topic. My application read message for topic and request some other service. I must control speed which i read and execute kafka message, because service very sensitive to hightload.
This code work fine

```
receiver.receive() // receive from input stream
.limitRate(rps*2)
.bufferTimeout(rps, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.flatMap {
    Flux.concat(
        it.map {requestMyService(it)   }
    )
}
```

But i need change rps without reboot application, because at day i want 10 rps and at night i want 100 rps.
How can i change value in method `bufferTimeout` in runtime ?